# set background-image from localStorage base64 string

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64, local-storage

I have a function that encodes an image into base64 string and stores it into localStorage. I am trying to retrieve the image from localStorage and use it to set a background-image with jQuery.

Everything is working right, but the image isn't displaying. When I inspect the element in the browser, the single quotes around the 'data' uri aren't being inserted. I don't know if this is the problem or not.

Here is my code

function to encode and store image:

```
var img = document.getElementById("elephant");

function getBase64Image(img) {
    // Create an empty canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    // Copy the image contents to the canvas
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Get the data-URL formatted image
    // Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to
    // guess the original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg"
    // will re-encode the image.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
console.log(dataURL);

    return dataURL;     
}
```

jQuery to set the image:

```
localStorage.setItem("background" , getBase64Image(img));
console.log(localStorage);

background = localStorage.getItem("background")

console.log(background);

$("#elephant2").css('background-image' , 'url(' +background+ ')');
```

Comment: did you try using quotes  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the issue was missing quotes, but it was actually corrupted/incomplete base64 data string. I placed the function inside window.onload = function () so the image loaded entirely before converting to a string and it works like a charm/